# Discrete-time derivative of the sign function

Tags: discrete-mathematics, derivatives, partial-derivative, discrete-optimization

How does one calculate the time derivative of

$$
x_{k+1} = C_1\, \text{sign}(x_k-y_k)\sqrt{2\vert x_k-y_k\vert},
$$

with respect to $x_k$ ?

I know that the right part of the equation should yield
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial\,x_k} \sqrt{2\vert x_k-y_k\vert} = \frac{x_k-y_k}{\vert x_k -y_k\vert^{\frac{3}{2}}}.
$$

Yet, I don't know to get the final result. How can one differentiate the sign function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't differentiate the sign function.
The function $f(u) = \mbox{sgn}(u)\sqrt{2u}$
is simply an extension of $\sqrt{2u}$ to the entire real number line.
For $u > 0$, differentiate this as $\sqrt{2u}$, and
for $u < 0$, differentiate it as $-\sqrt{2u}$.
The function is not differentiable at $u=0$.